# Can I use a string to load an image in UI?

Tags: c#, image, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am creating an app that lets a user navigate a file browser in app, then having selected an image I would like to load that image into the scene, eventually I will like to create my own photo editing software.

The problem I have is that when the user has selected a file, it stores the file name using a ToString function, the file explorer closes and it opens a new UI Canvas in it's place. On this canvas, is there anyway of loading an image using the string I have stored? (It is all in the same scene)

I am not sure if this is allowed in one question but Is there also some way I can check to see if a JPG/PNG file has been selected?

Many thanks for any help or guidance that can be given!

Answer (score 1):

The string is most likely the path to the file on the disk. You need to load it on the RAM to play with it. Then you can use the Texture2D and Sprite classes to create and display:

```
public static void SetSpriteFromPath(string path, Image image)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) == true){ throw new ArgumentException(); }
    if(image == null) { throw new ArgumentException(); }
    if(File.Exists(path))   { throw new Argument Exception();  }

    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    if(bytes == null)
    { 
       Debug.LogError("Something went wrong with loading the file");
       return; 
    }
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    tex.LoadImage(bytes);
    Sprite sprite = mySprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    image.sprite= sprite;
}
```

Comment: I am new to this kind of accessing files in unity, how can use a string variable brought across instead of the "string path" you use at the beginning? I have tried calling it above this code as a new variable referencing the string but am not sure how to use this new variable.
For instance I have:

`public static string imageFromFile = FileBrowserImplementation.ImageSelected;`

and now I want to use this imageFromFile variable for all values.

Thanks for all your assistance though! I am very grateful!

Comment: I am not quite sure about what you describe there. You want to use imageFromFile everywhere but what does it contain? Is it a path?

Comment: Yes, it contains the path e.g. "c:\....\Pictures\example.png", but this path is stored as a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing web application then you need save it on server. Save server path for further processing because ones user selects the file on browser ToString() will save local file path.

I hope I understand your problem.

Avinash